# How to set a material icon using strings?

Tags: angular, google-material-icons

So I have to modify a mat card to include custom text and one of 3 icons (info, warning and danger, depending on the case). I have this in the html file:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="info icon" *ngFor="let icon">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
</mat-card>
```

and in the .ts file I don't know how to set the card to a specific icon, as strings won't work. Any ideas how I could do that? How do I assign a specific icon?

Comment: I tried setting `public icon="home";` and it works perfectly. What's `icon` in your case?

Comment: Problem was I was using ngFor instead of ngIf and that appeared to not display any Icon when setting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you have an unfinished *ngFor statement. It should be

```
*ngFor="let icon of someList"
```

Or maybe you wanted to do `*ngIf="icon"`
Passing the string is probably fine.

Comment: Thank you so much, indeed when using ngIf, passing the string is perfectly fine.